# Multidimensional array for data table

Tags: php, json

How to Select key values by index

I want to create datatable but I do not know how to select exact array[1] with key values. Now my datatable cycle returns nothing

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [success] => 1
                [error] => 0
                [error_note] => 
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [type_pay] => 0
                [oper_type] => 4
                [name_pay] => CLICK
                [name_oper] => Основной долг
                [time_pay] => 2016-05-01 00:00:00
                [amount] => 1461128
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [type_pay] => 1
                [oper_type] => 3
                [name_pay] => Наличные
                [name_oper] => Депозит
                [time_pay] => 2016-05-01 00:00:00
                [amount] => 207866
            )
```

I somehow started in PHP and decoded the Json into array

```
$data["reports"] = json_decode(file_get_contents('URL'), true);
```

Comment: I'd recommend starting by reading the [php manual pages for arrays](http://php.net/array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work for you, Use [PHP LIST](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to print key to value of an array ...

```
<?php 
$data['reports'] = array(
                0 => array
                    (
                        0 => array
                            (
                                'success' => 1,
                                'error' => 0,
                                'error_note' => ''
                            )

                    ),
                1 => array
                    (
                        0 => array
                            (
                                'type_pay' => 0,
                                'oper_type' => 4,
                                'name_pay' => 'MNP',
                                'name_oper' => 'OPQ',
                                'time_pay'=> '2016-05-01 00:00:00',
                                'amount' => 1461128
                            ),
                         1 => array
                            (
                                'type_pay' => 1,
                                'oper_type' => 3,
                                'name_pay' => 'XYZ',
                                'name_oper' => 'ABC',
                                'time_pay' => '2016-05-01 00:00:00',
                                'amount' => 207866
                            )
                        )
                    );  

foreach($data['reports'][1] as $key => $val)
{
    while(list($k, $v) = each($val)){
        echo $k.' : '.$v.'<br>';
    }
}   
?>
```

This will give you :

```
type_pay : 0
oper_type : 4
name_pay : MNP
name_oper : OPQ
time_pay : 2016-05-01 00:00:00
amount : 1461128
type_pay : 1
oper_type : 3
name_pay : XYZ
name_oper : ABC
time_pay : 2016-05-01 00:00:00
amount : 207866
```

***LIVE EXAMPLE : [CLICK HERE](https://eval.in/582620)***

Comment: I dont know why but it returns me ("Invalid argument supplied for foreach")

Comment: but as per your your array format, I'm using the same format then please verify format of your array and let me know @RavshanAbdurasulov

Comment: when I am debugging that comes for me which I putted in question however I do not know why this problem showing

Comment: @RavshanAbdurasulov Now I've replaced foreach loop in answer, try now

Comment: yes there only two code first my decoding and your cycle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113737/discussion-between-manjeet-barnala-and-ravshan-abdurasulov).